# What document/template was used for pgfplot manual?

Tags: templates, pgfplotstable, document-classes

I am trying to find out which template/document was used to generate the pgfplottable manual:
http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplotstable.pdf

Does anyone know where to find the template/document (if there is one)?

I really like how the pages are fairly 'full' with little margins and think it would work well for technical documents.

Thanks

Comment: The documentation lives here: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/code/ci/master/tree/doc/latex/pgfplots/

Comment: It's the `book` documentclass.  Margins are set using `\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.25cm,right=2.25cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}`.

Comment: Thanks, I go a similar results using the `article` class and the margins you provided!

Comment: @Jake Do you want to take any action here?

Comment: @Jake An answer would be nice to get this one off the list.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments